# Dplyr pipe - If this, continue, else end

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there an accepted way of constructing a dplyr pipe similar to the following:

```
data %>% {if(!is.null(data)) %>% else STOP} %>% ... %>% ...
```

I would like the pipe to continue if `data` is not null, otherwise I would like none of the further pipe to complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can.

If we start with the presumption that something down-pipe will fail (or do something *wrong*) if a condition is not met, such as

```r
NULL %>%
  mutate(cyl2 = cyl+2)
# Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
#   no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

then we can insert

```r
NULL %>%
  { stopifnot(!is.null(.)); .; } %>%
  mutate(cyl2 = cyl+2)
# Error in stopifnot(!is.null(.)) : !is.null(.) is not TRUE
#     x
```

(Notice we didn't get the fail about `'mutate' applied to an object of class "NULL"`.) In fact, if you want to get a *little* fancy, you can use R-4's new named `stopifnot` conditions:

```r
NULL %>%
  { stopifnot("data is null!" = !is.null(.)); .; } %>%
  mutate(cyl2 = cyl+2)
# Error in stopifnot(`data is null!` = !is.null(.)) : data is null!
```

It works (does not interfere) with real data:

```r
mtcars[1:2,] %>%
  { stopifnot(!is.null(.)); .; } %>%
  mutate(cyl2 = cyl+2)
#               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb cyl2
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4    8
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4    8
```